# Copy javascript error text to clipboard?

Tags: javascript

How do you copy javascript errors in IE to clipboard? CTRL + C doesn't work and I don't want to take screenshots. Are there any tools out there that lets you copy the text?

[image]

(ANSWER) EDIT: I finally found a machine which has IE8 on it and was able to copy the error message. It's a hassle, though.

Comment: IE6/7 still makes baby jesus cry. When will we be RAPTURED???

Comment: can't you use IE8? It has a button "copy error details" on error windows

Comment: Unfortunately, we're still stuck with IE7 at work.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using `IE8+` there is a new button called `Copy error details` to clipboard.

`IE7` or older, have done everything that is "easy", "de facto", "cultural" to something else, just to get your job harder.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes, the client still insists that it's 2002 and *it has to work in IE6* (oh, there is an IE8? OK, make it work in that, too.)

Comment: @Piskvor - Very true, that's exactly what happened in my previous project.

Answer (score 0):

IE allows you to use the method [window.clipboardData.getData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535220%28VS.85%29.aspx) to programatically copy data. I guess you could use this in a try/catch statement. But you will have to set permissions to use it, and it will only work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

These error messages in IE6/7 are rarely useful anyways, it's better to describe what you were doing when you experienced the error on which page. Because IE gives vague error messages and likes to concatenate all the javascript files together any line number that would have pointed to actual source of the problem is practically lost. Whomever is fixing the javascript is going to have to go through some grueling line by line medival debugging.

Edit: That is if the problem doesn't present in IE8, if it's present in IE8 as well, you have much better options.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctrl + C' to copy. It works in windows' alerts.